# Replicating a decision tree with rules gives different results than the model

Tags: python, decision-tree, trading, algorithmic-trading, quantitative-finance

I would appeciate any help regarding my problem, since I have tried to solve this for months.

I am trying to convert a decision tree model  (trading strategy) into a rule based trading strategy. After the model has been trained I parse the features, thresholds, splits from each node and save them in a text file using the code below. After that I save those same features, thresholds and splits of each node as a trading rule in another file. Here are some examples of some nodes which I converted into rules:

(([(0, 'l', '0.500000', 'has_medium'), 1], {'parent': 0, 'split': 'l', 'threshold': '0.500000', 'feature': 'has_medium'}), {'parent': 1, 'split': 'l', 'threshold': '-0.000042', 'feature': 'EURUSD_05:55:00_06:10:00'})

{'parent': 2, 'split': 'l', 'threshold': '0.000088', 'feature': 'EURUSD_04:10:00_04:25:00'}
(([(0, 'l', '0.500000', 'has_medium'), 1], {'parent': 0, 'split': 'l', 'threshold': '0.500000', 'feature': 'has_medium'}), {'parent': 1, 'split': 'l', 'threshold': '-0.000042', 'feature': 'EURUSD_05:55:00_06:10:00'})

{'parent': 2, 'split': 'r', 'threshold': '0.000088', 'feature': 'EURUSD_04:10:00_04:25:00'}
(([(0, 'l', '0.500000', 'has_medium'), 1], {'parent': 0, 'split': 'l', 'threshold': '0.500000', 'feature': 'has_medium'}), {'parent': 1, 'split': 'r', 'threshold': '-0.000042', 'feature': 'EURUSD_05:55:00_06:10:00'})

My backtester (trading simulator) then reads those rules and creates trading signals according to them.

However it seems that the trained model creates different predictions than the repilcated rule based model in the backtester.

It seems like the decision tree model would have some "Hidden" features which do not appear in the exported decision tree plot nor in the parsed nodes. In some cases the model predicted 1 where the rules where not met.

My questions:
Do you have any suggestions on how to analyze this problem?
Can there still be "hidden" features or filters in the decsion tree, which do not appear in the decision tree plot nor the exported nodes?
I have converted the features and splits to rules so that a left split is always <= (less or equal) and a right split is > (greater than) the threshold. Is this the correct way (I did not succeed in finding documentation about this, however Chat GPT gave such instructions)?

For coding I used python 3.10 and for the model scikit-learn.

The code I used for parsing the nodes:

```
    def get_lineage3(self, tree, feature_names,model_name):
        left = tree.tree_.children_left
        right = tree.tree_.children_right
        threshold = tree.tree_.threshold
        features = [feature_names[i] for i in tree.tree_.feature]

        # get ids of child nodes
        idx = np.argwhere(left == -1)[:, 0]

        nodes = {}  # List to store the nodes

        def recurse(left, right, child,ind, lineage=None):
            if lineage is None:
                lineage = [child]
            if child in left:
                parent = np.where(left == child)[0].item()
                split = 'l'
            else:
                parent = np.where(right == child)[0].item()
                split = 'r'

            p_threshold = '{:.6f}'.format(threshold[parent])
            p_feature = features[parent]
            lineage.append((parent, split, '{:.6f}'.format(threshold[parent]), features[parent]))
            node_ = {"parent":parent,"split":split,"threshold":p_threshold,"feature":p_feature}

            if parent == 0:
                lineage.reverse()
                return lineage, node_
            else:
                return recurse(left, right, parent, lineage), node_

        i = 0
        filename = self.report_features + model_name + '.txt'
        for child in idx:
            i += 1
            for node in recurse(left, right, child, i):
                # Open the txt file in write mode
                with open(filename, 'a') as txtfile:
                    txtfile.write(str(node))
                    txtfile.write("\n")
                print(node)
```